# a href click delaying document download to run Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, href

I am having an issue with some code.  I have a `href` link that will download a document once clicked.  For some reason this is interfering with my `jQuery getJSON`.

When I add `e.preventDefault()` my code executes perfectly.  When I comment out `e.preventDefault()` my `JSON` code never executes.

Here is my href link:

```
<a href="http://server:88/Documents/@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.path)" data-docid="@Html.Raw(Model.documentID)" class="btn documentLock" data-toggle="modal">
                                Download Word Version</a>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery('.documentLock').click(function (e) {
        // Stop the default behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        var object = jQuery(this);
        var docid = object.attr('data-docid');

        jQuery.getJSON("/Document/LockedStatus/" + docid, null, function (data) {

        })
        .fail('Could not communicate with the server, if this persists please contact the Computer department')
        .success(function (data) {
            if (data) {
                console.log(data);
                jAlert('This document is currently locked by and cannot be edited further', 'Document Locked');

            }
        });
    });
```

With `e.preventDefault` I get the console.log(data) to fire. with `e.preventDefault` it does not fire.  So I know the code works and it must be something to do with the link that downloads the document.

Comment: In success callback, try: `object.get(0).click()`

Comment: I'm lost.  Clicking the link will cause a page load, which means you won't even be on the same page when the `getJSON` call returns.  Do you want to stop the link working until after the call?

Comment: @A.Wolff I didn't see your comment here.  does the object.get(0).click() do the same as putting window.location = href; in my success callback?

Comment: @JamesWilson Ya, it will have same behaviour as it firing native click event (not jquery one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your code

```
.done(function() { 
window.location.replace("your url"); // give your url here

})
```

Here is your edited code

```
jQuery('.documentLock').click(function (e) {
    // Stop the default behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    var object = jQuery(this);
    var docid = object.attr('data-docid');

    jQuery.getJSON("/Document/LockedStatus/" + docid, null, function (data) {

    })
        .fail('Could not communicate with the server, if this persists please contact the Computer department')
        .success(function (data) {
        if (data) {
            console.log(data);
            jAlert('This document is currently locked by and cannot be edited further', 'Document Locked');

        }
    })
  .done(function () {
        window.location.replace("your url"); // give your url here

    });
});
```

Comment: I actually had to use e.preventDefault and then do a window.location after my Ajax executed.  Because I needed both to be completed.

Comment: after ajax call you what to redirect to the another page is that it?

Comment: Yeah so I just stashed the href into a var and at the end I window.location = href.  Only way I could get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

`href` attribute is jacked up.  If you could change it to `javascript:void(0);` or just a hashtag, that would probably help.

And why don't you use `.data()`?

Change this:  `var docid = object.attr('data-docid');` to this:

```
var docid = object.data('docid');
```

Comment: Why that? This is just wrong to wrap twice in a jquery object a DOM node

Comment: `jQuery()` is the same as `$()`

Comment: @Archer - There is no difference as you said... so guess no need to change anything.